# Are verbs "to run" as in "to run a business" and "to run" as in "to run a marathon" considered to be homonyms/homographs?

Tags: verbs, homonyms, homographs

Or is there just a single verb "to run" that has different meanings and therefore it cannot be considered a homonym/homograph to itself?

Comment: [**homonym**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/homonym) - *each of two or more words having the same spelling or pronunciation but different meanings **and origins***. Since ***to run*** has the same etymology in both your examples, they're just ***the same word** [with different meanings]*, not homonyms as normally understood. Btw - it's ***a** homonym*, not ***an** homonym* (unlike, say, ***an** historic occasion*, there's no scope for personal choice on that one).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Could you write an answer, please?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - are you attacking his choice of article??  I thought we didn’t condone ***an homonym*** attacks on ELU. :-)

Comment: @aparente001: I'd already closevoted for lack of prior research before posting that comment. I assume just about *any* definition of "homonym" would include the point about *different etymological history*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Personally, I had never given any thought to this.  If there's a duplicate then that would be a good reason to close.  If not, I think it deserves an answer.  Just my two cents.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for sharing this particular definition and effectively answering my question. Unfortunately your assumption doesn't seem to be correct, as the first definition of a homonym that mentions the origin comes 7th on Google search. Top results that I have consulted before posting this question were:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homonym
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/homonym
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/homonym

Comment: Definition #3 from top at dictionary.com suggests: " a word of the same written form as another but of different meaning and usually origin, whether pronounced the same way or not". Note the "usually". This doesn't strike me as crystal clear to be honest.

Comment: @Dmitry Aleks: Your M-W link defines "homonym" as *one of two or more **words** spelled and pronounced alike but different in meaning*. To me (and most lexicographers and Anglophones in general) both your ***run*** examples feature *the same word*, so homonymity isn't an issue. It looks the same with all your other definitions. Your confusion stems from mistakenly thinking that *to run = to manage* and  *to run = to sprint, race* are ***different words***.

Comment: ...note that some dictionaries include the caveat ***usually** different origins* because there can be some confusion in that area. At the end of the day, if native speakers are totally unaware of an etymological connection between two "words" that sound the same but have wildly different meanings, it makes sense to call them homonyms even if lexicographers know perfectly well they're just "the same" word which has evolved down two different pathways over time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I didn't know whether those two "to run" verbs are the same word or not and never stated that I thoughts they are not . If you look at the body of my question it is easy to see that I mentioned "is there just a single verb" part as the key to answering my question. What I didn't know for sure was whether it was the same word or not, and therefore I asked the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Another thing that is admittedly less apparent from my question is that I intuitively believed that there is just a single word. I was prompted to ask this question to find out whether I'm wrong or why exactly I'm right, as I couldn't find a definitive answer after 10 minutes of googling. I didn't state my personal belief at a time as it couldn't find a concrete backing for it so it was no more that intuitive guess that didn't seem to contribute much to the question should it have been included.